# Misleading "protected" message on closed question shown to users who are not logged in or have less than 10 on-site rep

Tags: bug, closed-questions, protected-questions

[Should I choose Doctrine 2 or Propel 1.5/1.6, and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48760/should-i-choose-doctrine-2-or-propel-1-5-1-6-and-why)

Is this the intended behavior?

I was searching for the "answer" button because I read that I need at least 10 reputation because the question is protected. I have more than 10 reputation on that site.

Turns out the question is actually closed, in my opinion at the bottom it should point that out.

Comment: Where do you see a protected message?

Comment: at the very bottom "protected by ChrisF♦ Jan 6 '12 at 11:56"

Comment: I don't see it. Are you sure you have linked to the right post?

Comment: @Oded I see it [screen](http://gyazo.com/d071055e417ce4e492b1294b6b8448a8)  all the way at the botom of the page

Comment: Ah. I am logged in and have earned more than 10 rep on the site, so I don't see that. The question is both closed **and** protected. Nothing misleading there.

Comment: I'm logged in and have more than 10 rep on the site too.
The misleading thing is when you didn't see the message at the top, read some stuff, scroll to the to bottom to answer and it looks like you don't have enough rep.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you see? I don't see anything about protection on the question unless I look in the history. I only see a closed message.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: See the link in the comment from @Dimitrimx. I can reproduce the protection message if I open the message link in a private-browsing window (where I am not logged in), where it is shown *after all answers*. Also, when logged in, there is an `unprotect' option under the question.

Comment: I also do see it when not logged in.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard FWIW question (eg if it would be reopened) would be indeed protected from users like you. Protection is dropped only for users with 10 rep gained _on site_, association bonus doesn't count. See at MSE: [Improve “Protected Question” message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481/165773) and questions linked to it

Comment: *association bonus doesn't count* that seems to be the "issue" thanks.

Comment: well I would say that showing totally superfluous "need 10 repz to answer" message when question is closed (so that no amount of rep could help indeed) is an issue per se

Comment: that's my point, but I guess it's a rare scenario

Comment: related (probably not a duplicate): [Cannot Answer Protected Question with 101 Rep](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6633/31260)